# How to account for different baselines when analysing extremes in time series data

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, poisson-regression, offset

I want to see if Wikipedia articles for topics featured in popular documentaries get a boost in page views on the day the documentary is aired. I then want to see if time on screen is a predictor of this boost.

**I have to account for baseline popularity but I'm not sure how.** For instance, the Wikipedia article for global warming will have a different average number of hits per day than the article for acid rain.

My working solution has been to use the yearly average Wikipedia hits for each article as a baseline. I will have data on the number of hits for each article from the day the documentary aired. So I can calculated a percentage change from baseline to airing date (`doc_hits`).

```
Article         Wikipedia_baseline   doc_hits   %_change   seconds_on_screen 
global_warming  300                  450        50         60  
acid_rain       100                  260        30         160
plastics        250                  600        75         140
```

But if I feed this into a GLM, I'm worried I'm being circular e.g.

```
glm(%_change ~ seconds_on_screen + Wikipedia_baseline)
```

Here the `%_change` has been generated using the `Wikipedia_baseline` but I obviously need to take the popularity of the articles into account.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea seems sound, but it could be implemented better. `doc_hits` is a count variable, so a poisson distribution is a good starting point, but I am quite sure we will see overdispersion in this case, so I propose a quasipoisson family.  But you are interested in the `%_change`, that is, a rate. So you need poisson rate regression, then you use the number_of_views as response, and `Wikipedia_baseline` as an *offset*:

```
   glm(number_of_views ~ offset(Wikipedia_baseline) + seconds_on_screen, family=quasipoisson(), data= )
```

which is the correct form of your proposed model. Your problem also has time-series aspects, which I do not discuss in this answer, which is meant as a point of departure.

(an *offset* is a variable with a known coefficient of 1, which is not estimated).  Poisson rate regression is thoroughly discussed in [Goodness of fit and which model to choose linear regression or Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142338/goodness-of-fit-and-which-model-to-choose-linear-regression-or-poisson/142353#142353)  Other posts with examples is [Poisson Rate Regression: Offset?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30814/poisson-rate-regression-offset) and [How is a Poisson rate regression equal to a Poisson regression with corresponding offset term?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264071/how-is-a-poisson-rate-regression-equal-to-a-poisson-regression-with-correspondin)